# Intended invalid intialization from rvalue using *this

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue-to-rvalue

In C++ it is impossible to bind an r-value argument to a non-`const` l-value reference. But I noticed that when I call on the r-value object the method returning `*this` it compiles somehow.

Example:
Obliviously this snippet od code will not compile

```cpp
    class X
    {
    };
    
    void bar(X&)
    {
    }

    int main()
    {
      foo(X{}); //  invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'X&' from an rvalue of type 'X'
    }
```

But adding a simple method to `X` makes it compilable:

```cpp
class X
{
   public:
   X& foo() { return *this; }  
};

void bar(X&)
{
}

int main()
{
  bar(X{}.foo());
}
```

Why does it work? Does it mean that after calling `foo` r-value object becomes l-value object? Is it safe to use such construction? Is there any other way to achieve similar effect without creating a new method (something like `X.this`)?

Comment: The result of the function (the `X&`) is not an rvalue. If you try to change `foo` to return an rvalue reference (`X&&`), the compiler will not let you.

Comment: There's no such thing as "rvalue object" and "lvalue object".   The terms "rvalue" and "lvalue" refer to expressions. This is commonly mis-taught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, `foo` returns an lvalue, not an rvalue, so passing it to `bar` is just fine.

If it feels strange that `X{}.foo()` returns an lvalue even if `X{}` itself is an rvalue, think of `foo()` as a function which (implicitly) takes `this` and returns something (which happens to be what `this` points to) by lvalue reference. Now, how does `foo` take `this`? Does it accept rvalue? Does it accept lvalues? Yes to both, but you could write things so as to allow only one usage (look for *ref-qualified member functions* [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions)):

```cpp
class X
{
   public:
   X& fool() &  { return *this; } // called on lvalue objects
   X& foor() && { return *this; } // called on rvalue objects
};

void bar(X&)
{
}

int main()
{
    X x;
  bar(x.fool());
  //bar(x.foor());   // fails
  //bar(X{}.fool()); // fails
  bar(X{}.foor());
}
```

However, pay attention to what you do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
class X
{
   public:
   X& fool() &  { return *this; }
   X& foor() && { return *this; }
   ~X() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
};

void bar(X&)
{
}

int main()
{
  auto& xxx = X{}.foor();
  // use xxx, but X{} has been destroyed
  std::cout << "bye\n";
}
```